# Shell Script to Count the Occurrence of a Word in a file

Tags: shell

Lets take the below content as an example

```
    This file is a test file 
    this file is used to count the word 'file' in this test file
    there are multiple occurrences of word file in some lines in this test file
```

I want to count the word 'file' in the above content.

I'm using the below shell command

```
   cat $filename |  sed "s/_/new/g" | sed "s/$word/_/g" | tr -c -d _ |wc -c
```

Is that ok or any better ideas ..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using tr for separating words and then grep and wc seems possible :

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < file.txt | grep file | wc -l
```

Answer (score 7):

```
grep -cow "$word" "$filename"
```

The `-c` option specifies to report a count.

The `-o` option specifies to count each occurrence, not just the number of matching lines.

The `-w` option specifies to count word matches only, i.e. not partial matches such as "files" or "profiles".

Unfortunately, some versions of `grep` do not work correctly when you combine `-c` and `-o`.  If you have that bug, @Nykakin's answer is a good workaround.

Pay attention to the proper quoting of interpolated variables, also.

Comment: This will not count multiple occurences on the same line.

Comment: Updated; forgot the `-o` option which was the whole beef /-:  Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 6):

```
grep $word $filename -o | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the easiest method here which will be:

```
grep -c "file" filename
```

I you wish you strictly search for that word and no prefix and suffix then modify it as follows:

```
grep -wc "file" filename
```

Comment: This counts the number of lines which contain the word at least once, not the number of actual occurrences of the word.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat $filename | tr -s ' ' '\n' | grep -c $word
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it all in `awk` or `perl` and you can definitely remove the `cat` (sed can work on filenames too). `grep` by itself is a no-go, since it will only count one match per line.

```
$ sed "s/_/new/g" delmememetest | sed "s/$word/_/g" | tr -c -d _ |wc -c
7
$ grep -c file delmememetest
3
```

Let's try another funky approach, to make grep useful:

```
$ sed "s/${word:0:1}/\n&/g" delmememetest | grep -c "$word"
7
```

I insert a newline before each character that is the same as the first character of the search word. That way only one match per line does not interfere with the counting. If you have a recent version of GNU `grep`, the `-o` option used in another answer will ensure the same.

In any case, make sure the pattern you match against is not just `$word` or words with the same root will match too (or use the `-w` switch).

Comment: `grep -o` counts the actual number of occurrences, not lines.

Comment: I added a note just as you was tiping. It doesn't do any counting by itself, but it does delimit the output nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the voted solutions using the tr command couldn't handle the situation where there's linked word like "filefile". Here is my solution using Perl:

```
perl -p -e s/file/file\\n/g $filename | grep -c file
```

The -p tells perl to run a loop and to echo the output.
The -e specifies that the one-line program is coming next.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the easiest way:

```
 grep -o "$word" "$file" | wc -w
```

The `-o` option in `grep` specifies to count each occurrence, not just the number of matching lines.

The `-w` option in `wc` is to count only the whole words.

Answer (score 0):

This should work every time:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter the term"

read term

result=`grep -o $term file.txt | wc -l`

echo $result
```

Comment: No, this breaks if `term` contains whitespace or shell metacharacters. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) The [useless `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) is also mildly unsettling.

Answer (score -1):

...I like to keep it simple:

```
grep $string /file/name |wc -l
```

or

```
cat /file/name |grep $string |wc -l
```

Comment: The above answer may not work, person wants to know the count of word. what you are giving is effectively the number of lines where the word has been found

Comment: In addition to other bugs in several answers here, this suffers from [incorrect quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable). It's also hard to see how [using a useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) is simpler than not using it.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command :-
less fileName | grep wordToBeSearched | wc -l
Here less is the type of editor you want to use
If you wish to use nano editor, then use the following command :-
nano fileName | grep wordToBeSearched | wc -l
Here wc stands for word count and -l for the number of lines having this word.

Answer (score -2):

The code:

```
   count=0;
    for i in `cat $filename`;
        do if [ $i == "file" ];
    then ((count++))fi $i; 
    done;
    echo $count;
```